# MariaDB make SELECT wait for other transactions to finish

Tags: php, transactions, mariadb

I'm on **MariaDB 10.6.5**, and I have this code :

```
$pdo->query("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;");
$pdo->query("SET autocommit = 0;");

try
{
    $max_id = $pdo->query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM test")->fetchColumn();
    sleep(3);
    $insert_sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES(:test)");
    $insert_sql->execute(['test' => $max_id + 1]);
}
catch (Throwable $e)
{
    $pdo->query("ROLLBACK;");
}

$pdo->query("COMMIT;");
```

The `test` table has two columns : `id` (auto incremented) & `test` (int).

When two users execute this code at the same time, I want the first transaction to lock the `test` table at the `SELECT` statement and for the second transaction to wait at the `SELECT` statement for the first one to finish.
If everything goes well, the `id` column should always be equal to the `test` column.

Is this possible ? And if so, how ?

For clarification, here's what I want to happen :

- Two users `U1` and `U2` run this code at the same time, `U1` runs it a few microseconds earlier
- `U1` runs the `SELECT` statement, locking the table `test`
- `U1` runs the `INSERT` statement
- `U1` runs the `COMMIT` statement, unlocking the table `test`
- `U2` runs the `SELECT` statement, reading the new `MAX(id)` after the `INSERT` of `U1`
- `U2` runs the `INSERT` statement
- `U2` runs the `COMMIT` statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GET_LOCK`

add the query `DO GET_LOCK('lockname', 30)` at the start and `DO RELEASE_LOCK('lockname')` after the query.

So when User 1 starts the query it sets the lock `lockname` and only releases it when finished, If User 2 starts the script `DO GET_LOCK('lockname', 30)` waits for the lock to be released before continuing.