INSERT only if row with specific conditions does not exist - with some concerns about concurrency and atomicity
I need to insert a row in a table only if a row with a specific set of conditions is not already found in that table.
Given that this problem is (extremely) common, I searched through answers and came up with the following page:
How can I do 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?
I don't want to use INSERT IGNORE or other MariaDB/MySQL-specific statements if possible, so I especially looked at the second (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3025332/19358731) and 7th (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9590881/19358731) answers.
Then, I remembered that single SQL statements are not atomic:
Is a single SQL Server statement atomic and consistent?
This makes me believe that the solutions provided in my first links are indeed wrong, as will potentially have many concurrent queries - I'm thinking that the SELECT subquery within each of the INSERT statement in these answers will not execute atomically within their respective parent INSERT statement.
I have two complementary questions:

is the solution (INSERT INTO table SELECT ... NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)) provided in my first link indeed right? Are the queries indeed safe (atomic)?
in addition to my first question, can I also use the following PHP code to fulfill my needs (performance will just be lower I imagine):

$pdo->query('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE');
$pdo->beginTransaction(); 
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ... FROM table WHERE conditions LIMIT 1");
$statement->execute();
if ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
  $statement2 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table ...");
  $statement2->execute();
}
$pdo->commit();


Your second question link is for SQL-Server, not MariaDB. In MySQL and MariaDB, there's an implicit transaction around each query unless you start an explicit transaction.

Either of your methods should work. In general, you want to minimize the number of queries you send to the server, so the first method may be preferred.

It can also be used when you're running queries directly, rather than from a programming language with conditionals.

Is the data unique for the table? If so a unique constraint might be best.

@Barmar correct, but the default isolation level for a transaction with MySQL is REPEATABLE READ, not SERIALIZABLE. Is REPEATABLE READ sufficient in this case to guarantee that no row with the same set of conditions will be inserted? Or are you saying the default isolation level for an implicit transaction is SERIALIZABLE?

@user3783243 no, it is not unique.

Sorry, I don't know the details of the isolation level.

You don't need a transaction here. What you are looking for is called table locking. Although some certain transaction isolation level may lock a table for you but for the life of me I won't understand why would you use that instead of just explicit lock. That said, if you can make your whatever obscure "conditions" into just unique index, the task will be come a piece of cake.

@YourCommonSense you're right, LOCK TABLES table WRITE; lookup statement/conditional insert statement(s) ; UNLOCK TABLES; would best work. Otherwise, a SERIALIZABLE ("slow") transaction is required, as I need to prevent INSERTs in concurrent transactions, and as is nicely illustrated in the last example here valid for MSSQL but probably also for MariaDB: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4438/compare-repeatable-read-and-serializable-sql-server-transaction-isolation-levels/

An application lock can also be used and should be faster than a table lock : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72801107/19358731

Not sure how a write lock would help against concurrency issues. One thread will read  current value and set write lock. Another thread will read current value, then curret thread will set the new value and release the lock. then another thread will set the lock and update the same value.

Given you already mentioned  INSERT IGNORE, it seems that unique index is possible. So this must be your course of actions. Instead of INSERT IGNORE there are thousands other  solutioins, catching and ignoring exception on PHP side is one

About the write lock: LOCK TABLES table WRITE is needed for other sessions to wait until the table can be both written to and read from, this latter feature is the thing important for my operation. Regarding the unique index, I agree things may be investigated on my side, but I purposefully ruled it out since I have other scenarios like the one mentionned here that fit in a more general context.

INSERT INTO t
    ( SELECT ...
        FROM      my_table AS t
        LEFT JOIN my_table AS u ON ...
        WHERE u.id IS NULL );

That should be atomic, thereby not necessarily needing any TRANSACTION stuff.  Also, it will avoid "burning" AUTO_INCREMENT" ids in t`.
Note the "self join".
This shows how to do normalization en masse with similar code:
Normalization

What is the u table in your code? I have a single table.

@andynewman - Perhaps the edit I made helps.

Thank you. However, according to the 4th link I gave, this code may raise a deadlock, even if I enclose it in a SERIALIZABLE transaction. The following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21469107/19358731, discussing a similar UPDATE issue, adds an UPDLOCK and HOLDLOCK. Isn't something like this necessary in my INSERT scenario?

@andynewman - SQL Server does not work the same as MySQL/MariaDB.  Do not expect the link you ave to be of much use.
